# iframe spill out of div container when aligning to the left

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I am trying to add a Twitter iframe to my website's home page. I want the iframe to align to the left inside of the div container. The problem is, whenever I align it to the left, it spills out of the div yet when I align to the right, it fits perfectly.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening? And how to fix it?

This is the code I am using for the div/iframe:

```
<article>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="container"> 
        <iframe src="https://www.twitter.com" width="270" height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
    </div>
</article>
```

This is the CSS I am using to style:

```
.container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    width: 1200px;
    display: absolute;
}

iframe {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

I just want it to fit inside of the div on the left, not at the very edge or spilling out. Also, I am using Chrome, but I notice my iframe doesn't display on Edge, is there a reason for this? I don't get any errors, it just comes up as a blank, gray box.

I may have this solved soon, so I thank everyone in advance who has any advice to offer!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the iFrame CSS it contains `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. You then have a float left. Margin auto on left and right will center the element. Remove the `margin-left: auto`. You also have `text-align: center`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was a typo when writing this question or not, but there is no `absolute` value for the `display` property.

Switching `display` to `position` results in this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  width: 1200px;

  /* Removed "display: absolute;" */
  position: absolute;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article>
  &nbsp;
  <div class="container">
    <iframe src="https://www.twitter.com" width="270" height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
  </div>
</article>
```

which sounds like what you're looking for as it prevents the iframe from overflowing. Of course, there are other ways to align things to the right or left, such as[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).